# python- os.system() not properly opening then immediately closing file

Tags: python

I am trying to get a python script to open another python script in a directory that I know of but the actual filename is a variable. I would like to execute this file or be able to import the file (either way would work for what I am trying to do) but I am having problems with each one.

for trying to execute it, the dos style box appears but quickly disappears, too quickyl to really do anything. I even added a Raw_Input() and executed the file on its own and got it to work. here is the like on code:

```
os.system("python actions/"+Script)
```

Script being the name of the python file in a string. I know that the file is found but the problem is that it disapears too quickly

the other way I am trying to do it is by importing the file:

```
import 'actions/'+Script
```

this is the only logical way I can think of to import the damn thing but I keep getting syntax errors

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`__import__` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) to import a module whose name isn't known until runtime:

```
# Import the module
mymodule = __import__('actions/' + Script)

# Call functions in the module etc.
mymodule.do_something(42);
```

Comment: I got this error:                                                 ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Or try **import** (been around a while I believe) or importlib (added in python 2.7):

import">http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#**import**
http://docs.python.org/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
import sys
sys.path = ["./actions"] + sys.path
exec("import " + Script[-3])
```

Comment: import actions/email.py
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: got the error above, sorry accidently hit enter before i wanted to post